# Correctly way to find some variable with 2 case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find some variable from 2 different element patterns.

```
var something = $('.class').attr('data-something');

if(typeof something === 'undefined') {
    var something = $('.class').attr('data-another'); 
}

if(typeof something != 'undefined') {
    // do action...
    console.log(something); 
}
```

I just want to get some data from attr `data-someting="mydata"`

And if `data-someting="mydata"` not found so find a data form `data-another`

Then do action....

Im doing right ? or another correctly way to do better ?

Whats about `Try Catch` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers will have it `undefined` while some will return `false`. So, here is a more robust version:

```
if (typeof something === 'undefined' || something === false) {
    // try another attribute
} else {
    // do your stuff
}
```

*Update:*

Hm, accroding to [the doc](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns `undefined` for attributes
>   that have not been set.

So, probably, they are explicitly ensuring this themselves as of 1.6 and my information about `false` is outdated. In this case your own code is perfectly correct.

Comment: I never knew some browsers will return `false`

Comment: Probably my information about `false` is outdated, see update.

Comment: Thanks I will check both as your told :D

Comment: I'd also suggest to use this syntax: `if ($('.class').is("[data-something]")) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

You can/should access data properties using $.data();

e.g

```
var something = $('.class').data('something');
```

Comment: One maybe off topic question... Why I should use `.data()`

Answer (score 1):

```
 var something = $('.class').attr('data-something') || $('.class').attr('data-another')
```

This will do for both `undefined` and `false` values

Comment: What if the attribute is an empty string? ;) The problem with implicit boolean cast (as with `if`) is that it is unstrict…

Comment: @kirelagin +1 But this working fine for me. Give me some example pls

Comment: `<img data-something="">` the attribute is obviously present, but this code will ignore it.

Comment: @l2aelba, @kirelagin means that an empty string will be cast to `false` and thus treated as absence of attribute (and he is correct)

Comment: Anyway this depends on your logic, if you intent to skip empty strings and traverse to other attribute, then this solution will do for you.

Comment: @kirelagin , Atur Udod, I do both your 2 answers like http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/8NteU/ ... This right ?

Comment: @l2aelba, not really, you're doing my solution, not kirelagin's. As been mentioned, this is not correct if you want to utilize empty strings as valid values. And btw I believe `0` will be also cast to false.

Comment: So to sum the things up: I recommend you to use @kirelagin solution, and even more likely this solution: `if ($('.class').is("[data-something]")) {...}`

Comment: `0` won't be cast to `false` because attributes are strings, and `'0'` is not an empty string, so it is `true`.